# Send a localhost link to an email in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localhost, email

I created a password recovery page which sends an email to a user containing a link to another page where he can reset his password. Here is my code file..

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBS_WINDOWS7;Initial Catalog=LMS;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT AccountID, Password FROM tblAccount Where Email= '" + txtEmail2.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
            }
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                // Sender e-mail address.
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail2.Text);
                // Recipient e-mail address.
                Msg.To.Add(txtEmail2.Text);
                Msg.Subject = "Your Password Details";
                Msg.Body = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + @"Login.aspx?id=id";
                    Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                // your remote SMTP server IP.
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test.email@gmail.com", "dummypassword");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                //Msg = null;
                lbltxt.Text = "<i class='icon-check-sign'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;We have sent your password. Go check it out!";
                lbltxt.CssClass = "alert alert-success";
                // Clear the textbox valuess
                txtEmail.Text = "";
                txtEmail2.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                lbltxt.CssClass = "alert alert-error";
                lbltxt.Text = "<i class='icon-question-sign'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Something went wrong. Are you sure that's your email with us?";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
    }
```

The email sending works perfectly but the link that I am trying to display is not clickable and the `@"Login.aspx?id=id";` code line is printed directly on the email sent.

This project is hosted on localhost by the way.

**So my question is:
Why doesn't this code create a clickable link to the page where a user is supposed to reset his password? Can someone share their thoughts on this?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are missing to put the login url inside of a link, e.g: <a href="your login url">Login</a>

Comment: ^ I tried adding an `<a href='@Login.aspx?id=id'>Links</a>` but my browser redirected me to `http://www.login.aspx/?id=id` and not the page where he is supposed to be directed. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
Msg.Body = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + @"Login.aspx?id=id";
```

to read this:

```
Msg.Body = String.Format("<a href='{0}/Login.aspx?id=id'>Link</a>", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);
```